# Avoid Overlapping between 2 Text in reactNative

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

i have 2 text in one view , the 2 text are overlapping

Below are the 2 text styling.

```
<ChildText
            style={{
              textAlign: "right",
              width: 83,
              left: 44
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
            }}
          >
```

```
 <ChildTextTitle
            style={{
              width: 144,
              left: 10,

              
              textAlign: "right",
            }}
          >
```

How to prevent overlapping between the 2 text.

Comment: can you post while snippets with parent view holding both TextView?